# Visual Studio Makefile Project With several output

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile

I'm currently developing a C++ Solution in Visual Studio. My Solution relies on different thirdparty libraries and several projects of my own. Most of those projects rely on the same thirdparties, and thus, I created a Makefile project for each of these thirdparties libraries to save me some time with the linkage, since now I would only need to reference the thirdparty Makefile project.

One of those thirdparties outputs several .lib files, which on my Makefile project would like to config. So I went to project properties -> NMake -> Output. The thing is, it only seems to allow one output. Is it possible to put several .lib outputs? Am I doing the correct approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've searched far and wide and havent' found a solution for this. I think the only approach is to create a project for each .lib file. It's a bit of overwork, and it's easy for a solution with several external dependencies to grow large on projects.